# TypeScript - Array reduce return object with specific type/interface

Tags: typescript, array-reduce

I'm creating a generic function that gets properties from an object using array.reduce. I would like the return type to only return the type of properties extracted from the original object

```
type Sample = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  isAlive: boolean;
}

const sample: Sample = {
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 22,
  isAlive: true,
};

// What changes should I do here?
function getProps(...keys: (keyof Sample)[]) {
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = sample[key];

    return acc;
  }, {})
}

const result = getProps("name", "age");
/*
  I would like the result to have a type of:
  {
    name: string;
    age: number;
  }
*/
```

I saw this being done in zustand.js but I don't know how they did it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution. The key is using generics and the `Pick` utility type:

```js
type Sample = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  isAlive: boolean;
}

const sample: Sample = {
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 22,
  isAlive: true,
};

function getProps<K extends keyof Sample>(...keys: K[]): Pick<Sample, K> {
  return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = sample[key];
    return acc;
  }, {} as Pick<Sample, K>)
}

const result = getProps("name", "age");
// result has only name and age
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyghgWzAG2gXigbwFBSgO0QgC4oBnYAJwEt8BzAblyjjpIIFcEAjCSpvNTIBBZNQBu7bgHtpqOPiYBfbNgDG0-BXKIU7eElRQMOPIQTsARAClpAC3xQAItIiWANM1bsATD8+CImKSpFQcEJ5KTNgA9DFQAOp2cMBQasn0EGTkdtIcyAAmUACSUAXSUHZ8EAD82ABmHPhqwNSaUGzAAAqU0mBkADwA0lAQAB7AEPgF2QDWECDS9bC6qAB8ABQAdDvzIGSkQwDaALoAlKRd1GqzAwZ67lBDa1jMlBDAHJSOe2Rb7wUOGoIBsNnA1GpHnszsYXqY8CwIUc9idjDpDBBkQsTgIEe9Pt9EWpcUpHpglCxslcbndVhEnmsztgVOpNNp3mR8qkMJ0en0yBtLOY3I9LN5LGcmEA)

Comment: I was just about to post a similar solution but would have used just `keyof` instead of `extends keyof`. What's the motivation behind this?

Comment: I didn't know the solution is this simple, thanks! My only minor problem with this is type hinting / autocomplete in VS Code, if I do ```getProps("name")``` the next time I put another parameter VS Code will only suggest ```"name"```

Comment: @alexanderdavide ```<K keyof Sample>``` is not a valid syntax

Comment: @CRIS I'm talking about something like `<Record<keyof Sample, Sample[keyof Sample]>`.